# Transfering music from external hard drive to iphone (without copying to disk)

Tags: itunes, music

I have a large collection of mp3s (a backup of my old itunes from another computer) and I want to copy this to my new IPhone.

Trouble is that my Mac is almost out of HD space, so I somehow want to copy the music directly from the external disk to the iPhone. I assume I can't do that from iTunes? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the location of your iTunes library to be on that external HD. And then add those songs and sync your phone.

The preference in questions is in iTunes Preferences > Advanced and the top option allows you to choose the location of your iTunes library

Comment: I did that, and when I go to iTunes to see the library, it still only shows the local files that are on my mac, not the ones on the external disk.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the music show in iTunes after setting the location of the library? Does it take a while to import perhaps?

Comment: You can't just point iTunes to a folder full of music. You need to point it to a location that you want the library to be and then add the songs **or** point it to an iTunes library that you moved there.

Comment: Oh I believe this copy I have is an exact copy of my iTunes library of an old computer (it has the iTunes folder), so the latter might work? But I did not see any way to add it or import it. So I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Then you may have to manually re-add all your music and recreate all your playlists.